# ¿Alguien sabe por qué cuando quiero actualizar un campo con Mongoose se borran los otros campos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose, discord.js

**- Les cuento:**

Este es el esquema:

```js
const { model, Schema } = require("mongoose");

const test = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String },
    item: {
        field_1: { type: String, default: 1 },
        field_2: { type: String, default: 2 },
        field_3: { type: String, default: 3 },
    },
});

module.exports = model("test", test);
```

Si no hay ningún documento, creará el documento con un nuevo valor del campo "field_1"., vean:

```js
if (!document) {
    await new data({
        _id: interaction.guildId,
        item: { field_1: 10 },
    }).save();
}
```

El documento se crea y tiene el siguiente aspecto:

```json
{
    "_id": "123456789123456789",
    "item": {
        "field_1": "10",
        "field_2": "2",
        "field_3": "3"
    },
    "__v": { "$numberInt": "0" }
}
```

Pero en caso de que el documento exista, quiero que actualice el campo, se supone que es así, ¿no?

```js
if (!document) {
    // Código anterior que no volveré a escribir.
} else {
    await data.findByIdAndUpdate(interaction.guildId, {
        item: { field_1: 10 },
    });
}
```

Al actualizar el campo seleccionado, ocurre lo siguiente:

```json
{
    "_id": "123456789123456789",
    "item": {
        "field_1": "10"
    },
    "__v": { "$numberInt": "0" }
}
```

Actualiza el primer campo pero elimina los otros dos, no debería porque tienen un valor por defecto. ¿Alguien sabe por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: Para actualizar un subdocumento, debes usar la notación de punto: `{"item.field_1": "1"}`. Saludos

Comment: Por cierto, declaras tu campo de tipo `String` pero usas valores numéricos. ¿Porqué?

Comment: @MauricioContreras 
Lo que envié fue una prueba pero sí, tienes razón, debería haber puesto un texto, puse números sólo por poner algo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, asi reemplazas el documento, tienes que usar $set

```
await data.findByIdAndUpdate(interaction.guildId, {
   $set: { "item.field_1": 10 },
});
```

Comment: Tampoco, estás reemplazando `item`, aunque uses `$set`. Eso significa que vas a establecer el valor del campo `item` al objeto que pasas como valor. Se debe usar la notación de punto. Saludos

Comment: Tienes razón, ya corrijo. Saludos